# How To Read Files From HTTP POST

Tags: java, http

How to read files (zip and xml formats) that are delivered to web server from a client application via HTTP POST using java

Comment: Let's guess which web server you're using.  I vote that you're using JRun.

Comment: I guess you are using servlets?

Answer (score 1):

[commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) is a library to use on the server to read uploaded files. Read the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html)